# Did the myth of carrots improving eye sight begin as WWII propaganda?

Tags: nutrition, propaganda

I've often heard that the myth that eating carrots helps you see better at night (not to be confused with carrots helping with vitamin A *deficiency*) was started by the British in World War II, as propaganda to help conceal the fact that the RAF planes were equipped with radar. The story was that the RAF were able to find the German planes at night because their pilots were able to see very well in the dark due to eating a lot of carrots, and not because they were flying around with nifty gadgets.

The [Smithsonian Magazine](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/a-wwii-propaganda-campaign-popularized-the-myth-that-carrots-help-you-see-in-the-dark-28812484/) website summarized it:

> During the 1940 Blitzkrieg [of Britain], the Luftwaffe often struck under the cover of darkness. In order to make it more difficult for the German planes to hit targets, the British government issued citywide blackouts. The Royal Air Force were able to repel the German fighters in part because of the development of a new, secret radar technology. The on-board Airborne Interception Radar (AI), first used by the RAF in 1939, had the ability to pinpoint enemy bombers before they reached the English Channel. But to keep that under wraps, according to Stolarczyk’s research pulled from the files of the [Imperial War Museum](http://www.iwm.org.uk/visits/iwm-london), the Mass Observation Archive, and the UK National Archives, the Ministry provided another reason for their success: carrots.

Was this when the myth started? Or was the idea already out there in the public consciousness, and it was just exploited/popularized by the British Ministry of Information?

For example, were there popular writings from the '30s (newspapers, books, notable studies, etc) that were already making the leap from "vitamin A deficiency causes night blindness, so mega dosing vitamin A will *enhance* night vision", similar to the contemporary myth that "oxidants kill cells, so mega dosing antioxidants will keep you from aging"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does eating carrots improve your eyesight?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/does-eating-carrots-improve-your-eyesight)

Comment: @DJClayworth I think that question is about the carrot-eating myth itself, while this question is about the origin of the myth. This myth has a pretty clear and popular "claim" to its origin, so that claim is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Is anybody claiming that the myth predated WW2? Multiple reliable sources say it originated with WW2 propaganda. Obviously the effect of carrots on people with vision loss due to vitamin A deficiency was known before.

Comment: @DJClayworth While I do see a lot of sources saying that it originated with WWII, I also see a lot of references to it being _popularized_ in WWII, rather than _originating_ from the propoganda. In the Smithsonian link I provided above, one of their sources is John Stolarcyzk, and there is a paragraph that begins with "[John] Stolarczyk is not confident about the exact origin of the faulty carrot theory".

Comment: Also your link in the question does not go to Stolarczyk’s research, but to the IWM general site. Can you give us a link for Stolarczyk’s claim?

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry, to clarify my Stolarczyk comment, that quote was taken from the Smithsonian article itself, not from any original research from Stolarcyk. My point was that the Smithsonian article is fuzzy on where the carrots-give-you-night-vision claim originated from, but is clear in stating that it was popularized in WWII.  I just wanted to know if this was something that people already thought and that the British exploited, or if it was a wholly new concept.

Comment: This is the same question as was asked in the duplicate. It's perfectly fine to go and add a new answer to that question if you think the current one is wrong, but it doesn't make sense to ask the question again.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm not trying to be obtuse about this, but I'm still having trouble understanding how this is the same question as the one that you've linked to. This question asks about the popular origin story of a claim, while the question you've linked to is about whether that claim is true or false. It's like having a question saying "was Columbus the first European to discover the new world", versus "did Columbus find it so difficult to find financiers for his journey because his contemporaries thought the world was flat". Just because they revolve around Columbus, doesn't make them dupes.

Comment: They still look like duplicates to me. It's more like asking "Who was the first European to discover the New World?" and getting the answer "Columbus", and then asking "Was Columbus the first European to discover the New World?" and expecting a different answer. Both of the questions are wanting to know what the origin of the carrot myth is.

Comment: @DJClayworth "_Both of the questions are wanting to know what the origin of the carrot myth is_" - this is likely where my confusion is coming from. I don't see anything at all in the linked question that asks about the varsity of the origin story about the myth...It just asks if the myth is true. The answer on the question essentially says "the myth is not true; in fact, here's the story of how it started", and I don't think it would be appropriate to comment to ask "is this origin true?"

Comment: I've opened a [meta question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4362) about this question being a duplicate. Hopefully the longer form of an answer will allow for somebody to help me grasp what I'm not seeing here, so that I'm not posting more dupes in the future.

Comment: @RToyo I have deleted my answer for now and will add it back after making some edits. How do you think I can improve my answer to better address your question? I looked back at the website of the founder of the World Carrot Museum. There is a very interesting statement: "famously, the UK food ministry responded to a temporary wartime oversupply of carrots by suggesting, through propaganda," [here](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/history4.html). This means that the interviewee himself didn't allege the War Ministry (or Information ministry) started the story. The Smithsonian article says ...

Comment: ..."Information Ministry," your snippet didn't include this information. Also, scroll down to the comments on the Smithsonian article. The World Carrot Museum writes "There was no "extreme surplus of carrots" of the end of the war. There was some surplus in the middle of the war. **This was nothing to do with the night sight campaign and all to do with the government's plan to increase production of carrots and other home grown vegetables, to ensure that there was an adequate supply of a foodstuff not on ration and able to be used as a viable alternative to those which were not.**...

Comment: ...The rational way to do this ws to over produce so that there WAS a surplus -better than having yet another shortage." in response to another comment. He never alleges the  British Ministry of Information started the myth. He calls this the Smithsonian's twisting of his words to increase journalistic value. (Contact him and he will deny it.)

Comment: Sorry for the long comments, just meant to say: Ask me anything about this, I will add it to the answer, then undelete it. 1 last thing: I contacted both the RAF museum and the World Carrot Museum. Ping me in chat to see the correspondence.

Comment: 1 last thing: I contacted both the RAF museum and the World Carrot Museum. Ping me in chat to see the correspondence. The summary is: RAF museum held firm with their viewpoint; World Carrot Museum said the Smithsonian twisted their facts and that the Ministry of Food started the myth and not the "Ministry of Information." Also, the World Carrot Museum quickly points out that this isn't a myth and that it helps when you have Vitamin A deficiency. (None of the above are necessarily my viewpoints.) Again, ping me in chat. I will be happy to *discuss* there.

Comment: Here's a source from 1942 claiming a carrot / vitamin A / eyesight link: https://archive.org/details/vitaminsinwartim1942unit/page/n1?q=eyesight

Comment: @shoover Great find! It's a really interesting read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Please suggest improvements for the answer in the comments.*

From the  Smithsonian article cited in the question:

> But to keep [[British radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_Interception_radar#AI_Mk._IV)] under wraps, according to Stolarczyk’s research pulled from the files of the Imperial War Museum, the Mass Observation Archive, and the UK National Archives, the Ministry provided another reason for their success: carrots.

Basically, the story is saying that the myth of carrots improving eye sight begin as WWII propaganda to fool the Germans from believing the British had new radar systems. **This is not true.**

According to [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-carrots-improve-your-vision/) (emphasis added):

> But [Bryan Legate](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/bryan-legate-50792365), **assistant curator at the Royal Air Force Museum** in London has a different view. “I would say that whilst the [British] Air Ministry were happy to go along with the story [of carrot-improved vision], **they never set out to use it to fool the Germans**,” Legate says. “The German intelligence service were well aware of our ground-based radar installation and would not be surprised by the existence of radar in aircraft. In fact, the RAF were able to confirm the existence of German airborne radar simply by fitting commercial radios into a bomber and flying over France listening to the various radio frequencies!” he adds.

I [contacted](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/) the World Carrot Museum as well as the [RAF Museum](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/contact-us/). The correspondence supported the statements above. Ping me in chat/comments for the transcripts.

From the World Carrot Museum's [dedicated page](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/ww2seeinthedark.html) on the myth.

> The truth is that whilst the British Air Ministry were happy to go along with the story of carrot-improved vision, they never set out to use it to fool the Germans.

and [here](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/history4.html)

> Famously, the UK Food Ministry responded to a temporary wartime oversupply of carrots by suggesting, through propaganda, that the RAF's exceptional night-flying and target success, was due to eating high carotene content carrots. The suggestion worked and the consumption of carrots increased sharply because people thought carrots might help them see better in the blackout, thus taking pressure off the food supplies.

Thus, the myth was introduced not to trick the Germans into believing the British didn't have airborne radar, but to encourage consumption of carrots when they were in excess and the British didn't have many food sources.

The Germans introduced countermeasures to airborne radar by 1942 ([see here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52416/when-were-the-germans-aware-of-british-airborne-radar-during-wwii/52419#52419)). They would have knew of their existence earlier.

> Was this when the myth started?

**The myth was popularized around this time** in the hopes of increasing carrot consumption in the UK. As the myth was needed to increase carrot consumption, I assume the myth was either not widely known or nonexistent beforehand. However, I can't say when the myth started. Any search is populated with this particular incident of the myth; this version is definitely the most widely known.

> Or was the idea already out there in the public consciousness, and it was just exploited/popularized by the British Ministry of Information?

The British Ministry of Information didn't popularize the myth or actively use it to "trick" the Germans into believing airborne radar didn't exist. By 1942, the Germans had already developed countermeasures to British airborne radar. To develop such countermeasures, British airborne radar, of course, had to have been known by the Germans.

Comment: Please go and post this answer on the original question.

Comment: @DJClayworth What exactly do you mean? Could you clarify please? Thanks!

Comment: There is another question that asks exactly the same thing [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/does-eating-carrots-improve-your-eyesight). Would you be able to post this answer to that question too?

Comment: @DJClayworth It's got a perfectly good answer there and doesn't need another one :).

Comment: Would you be OK if I copied this information to that answer then?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, why not?

Comment: Some people don't like having their answers copied.

Comment: OK, I see. Links are provided, so it is easy to find the source material.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure this fully supports a "not true" conclusion. The article makes it sound like the British did indeed popularize the myth, and the only difference between the Scientific American article and the Smithsonian article in the OP, is that the intent was not to fool the Germans - and the reasoning behind that conclusion is is simply because the British were able to pick up German airborne radar, so the Germans might have picked up the British radar?

Comment: @RToyo I read it differently as disproving the Smithsonian story. Personally, I would trust a museum curator more than a random guy who started a "World Carrot Museum." However, that is my own personal feeling. I agree, this answer isn't the best it can be. I am still looking into the subject.

Comment: @RToyo Consider this: "in 1939, had the ability to pinpoint enemy bombers before they reached the English Channel" (from Smithsonian). Why not attribute this ability to ground based radar? (1) This is easier (2) Then, airborne radar will still be a secret. Going to the lengths of creating a carrot myth is harder.

Comment: Q "Did the myth begin as WWII propaganda?" A: "Yes, only not to fool the Germans, but to fool the British consumers?" (Or all sides of the Channel, really, with different aims and results?)

Comment: @LangLangC Yes, that's the vibe that I am getting from the World Carrot Museum. If you go [here](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/history4.html) and scroll down to "This secret reports on the Food Situation in 1941..." you can see a report that states "The consumption of carrots has increased following the Ministry [of Food]'s publicity campaign. Supplies are still ample."

Comment: OK. But I am pretty sure the vitamins-cure-all's had this in their self-help books before that (no proof yet, tho!) Heck, they sold women's tights with ascorbic acid in it ('anti-cellulitis', etc).

Comment: @LangLangC I am assuming that if the myth existed earlier, it wasn't well-known. The World Carrot Museum sites are saying carrot consumption increased after the start of the publicity campaign. There wouldn't be this increase if the myth was already well-known. But, that is based on correlation.

Comment: **Thanks for pointing this out.** Maybe somebody at the Ministry of Food was reading a vitamins-cure-all, saw this myth, and used this in the campaign. I wouldn't know.

Comment: Please have a look at old scientific literature, eg https://books.google.com/books?id=YJIrAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA1 My hunch here is that neither your A nor the other tell the whole story. Specifically I haven't found the other side of the story in scientific/historical lit: when and how did the RAF or the propagandists adopted this narrative of vision. The jump from 'crass improvement (if deficient)' to 'optimise above 100%  in healthy' is so common with med discoveries…

Comment: @LangLangC I guess you mean, "When did the propaganda start?"