# Can a lack of Vitamin A in your diet be statistically proven to be linked to worse eyesight?

Tags: medical-science, ophthalmology, vitamins

Reading this question: [Does eating carrots improve your eyesight?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/does-eating-carrots-improve-your-eyesight) - brought to mind a common piece of medical advice in USSR - to eat carrots to **prevent** your eyesight from going bad (as opposed to that question's claim to improve eyesight).

**Is it true that a lack of Vitamin A in your diet can be statistically proven to be linked to worse eyesight?**

Any definition of "worse" is acceptable for the purposes of this question, from abnormal eye pressure to nearsightedness to glaucoma to whatever else, though I personally am more interested in near-sightedness.

I don't have a cite for the claim but it was stated repeatedly by different doctors in USSR in my presence.

It sounds at least somewhat plausible in a sense of [certain diseases being obviously caused by vitamin deficiencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scurvy#Cause).

Comment: "Can" or "Does"? Define 'your'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deficiency of vitamin A most certainly can lead to worsening of eyesight and blindness.

A case study [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21319138) shows that correction of vitamin A deficiency resulted in reversal of night blindness. It's findings suggest that of all the eye structures effected by vitamin A deficiency, [rods](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/rodcone.html) and [S cones](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-iii-retinal-circuits/s-cone-pathways/) are more likely to be damaged than are [L and M cones](http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/montag/vandplite/pages/chap_9/ch9p1.html). Another case can be read [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19809843).

A study [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21491401) is not exactly on-topic but shows data which indicates that vitamin A supplements can prevent blindness in children infected with measles (which is a fairly rare consequence, but still noteworthy).

[*Loss of visual acuity or blindness due to deficiency of vitamin A from starvation or malnourishment is still a problem faced by many developing countries.*](http://www.childinfo.org/vitamina.html)

[It is also the leading cause of preventable childhood blindness worldwide.](http://www.who.int/nutrition/topics/vad/en/)

While it is true that a severe deficiency of vitamin A can dramatically worsen eyesight, there is no convincing evidence that an otherwise healthy person can increase his/her vision by consuming more vitamin A.

In fact, consumption of too much vitamin A results in hyperv[itaminosis A](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20395929) which can be fatal. For reference, one can check the case of Xavier Mertz, the Antarctic explorer who died of this condition.

Comment: @DVK I added the last paragraphs as an afterthought mainly to address  the two other questions about [carrots](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/does-eating-carrots-improve-your-eyesight) and [blueberries](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/does-bilberry-or-blueberry-improve-eyesight) which are very similar to this one, and people likely to visit those questions will probably also visit this one as well.

Comment: gotcha